Telnyx Sample Code for Outbound SMS not working
I have a project using c# / .NET Framework 4.8, and I am trying to integrate Telnyx for simple outbound SMS messaging.  I have installed the TELNYX.NET nuget package.  I've adapted the sample code from the TELNYX developer portal.  My code is as follows:
TelnyxConfiguration.SetApiKey("KEY01939D9F6C479B1E4A0FBF905CCC05BD_HjBhvrJVXllCBR1YTgjt0b");
       
  var message = Message.Create(new MessageOptions
  {
      From = "+18445550001",
      MessagingProfileId = "abc85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c9600000000",
      To = tmpPhone,
      Text = the_message,
      Subject = "VIJILCON ALERT",
      MediaUrls = new List<string> { "http://example.com" },
      WebhookUrl = "https://www.vijilcomm.com/webhooks1",
      WebhookFailoverUrl = "https://www.vijilcomm.com/webhooks2",
      UseProfileWebhooks = false,
      Type = "SMS"
  });

And I also have the appropriate Using reference:
using Telnyx;
But I am getting these errors:
CS0117  'Message' does not contain a definition for 'Create'
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MessageOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Which seems to indicate I'm missing the library.  Telnyx support has not been able to help me out.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.  This code is almost exactly as is adapted from their sample code.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you very much for your help!

For anybody using TELNYX, somebody in their slack community revised the code for me, and this is the corrected code that works for SMS outbound messaging with TELNYX:
TelnyxConfiguration.SetApiKey("KEY HERE");
// Initialize the MessageService
var messageService = new MessageService();

// Define message creation options
var newMessage = new NewMessage
{
    MessagingProfileId = Guid.Parse("4001939e-9e66-47f9-8bf5-29c3e0706250"), // Replace with your Messaging Profile ID
    From = "+FROMNUMBER",  // Replace with your sender phone number
    To = "+TONUMBER",    // Replace with recipient phone number
    Text = "Hello World",
    MediaUrls = new List<string> { "https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com" },
    WebhookUrl = "https://www.example.com/hooks",
    WebhookFailoverUrl = "https://backup.example.com/hooks",
    UseProfileWebhooks = true,
    ValidityPeriodSecs = 60  // Message validity in seconds
};

try
{
    // Create the message synchronously
    var message = messageService.Create(newMessage);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message created with ID: {message.Id}");

    // OR create the message asynchronously
    var asyncMessage = await messageService.CreateAsync(newMessage);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message created asynchronously with ID: {asyncMessage.Id}");
}
catch (TelnyxException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error creating message: {ex.Message}");
}

